# libreoffice calc: background color of cell based on background of other cell

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

LibreOffice Version: 6.4.7.2
Build ID: 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8

In libreoffice calc we can format styles: `Menu -> Styles -> Menage Styles`
Let's say I have formatted A1 cell so it is red when I type `wordA` into it, green when I type `wordB` when, yellow if `wordC` etc....

How do I force to change cell A2 to reflect same color as A1 ?
In other words: If I change **manually** value of `A1` I want to have both cells changed regardless of value inside A2.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible

Just write the [**conditional formatting**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/05120000.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=modules/scalc/ui/conditionalformatdialog/dialog-action_area1#bm_id3152518) correctly for all your cases and apply it to the correct range of cells:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this task is by writing a macro to change the color of one cell based on another cell. In LibreOffice you can write macros in four languages: LibreOffice Basic, Python, JavaScript, and BeanShell. Below I have used LibreOffice Basic, which is similar to VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).

The background color of a cell can be queried and set using `.CellBackColor`. Unfortunately, conditional formatting does not actually set the background color of a cell, but applies the coloring dynamically, so this property cannot be used to find out what the color of the source cell is.

Instead, you can recreate the conditional formatting in the macro. for example as follows:

```vb
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub ApplyColor
Dim src_cell as object
Dim tgt_cell as object
src_cell = ThisComponent.Sheets(0).getCellRangeByName("A3")
tgt_cell = ThisComponent.Sheets(0).getCellRangeByName("C1")

src_val = src_cell.getString()
Select Case src_val
   Case "wordA"
      tgt_cell.CellBackColor = rgb(255,0,0)
   Case "wordB"
      tgt_cell.CellBackColor = rgb(0,255,0)
   Case "wordC"
      tgt_cell.CellBackColor = rgb(196,180,84)
   Case Else
      tgt_cell.CellBackColor = rgb(255,255,255)
   End Select
End Sub
```

This code checks the value of cell A3 and sets the background color of cell C1 accordingly to red (255,0,0), green (0,255,0), yellowish (196,180,84) or white (255,255,255).

You can apply this macro automatically when the sheet contents is changed using the <kbd>Sheet</kbd>-<kbd>Sheet Events...</kbd> menu and choosing <kbd>Content Changed</kbd> and then <kbd>Macro...</kbd>. Note that this is a sheet-wide event listener, so you can also use it for any other formatting changes that apply to different cells.